# JS FireFox WebExtensions tabs.query(queryObj): can queryObj have an "or"?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-webextensions

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/query

```
var urls = ["url_pattern_1", "url_pattern_2"];
var titles = "title_pattern_1", "title_pattern_2"];
for (let url of urls) {
  for (let title of titles) {
    browser.tabs.query({"title": title, "url": url}).then((matched_tabs) => {
      // code to run on matched_tab
      }
    });
  }
}
```

If the `urls` and/or `titles` lists are long, this will cause `browser.tabs.query()` to be called many times. I'm curious (but not optimistic) if it's possible to have the query logical-OR all of the elements from the arrays so that I can get rid of the for loops.

Thanks!

Comment: It's not possible. Only thing you could do is create a title pattern that includes all of your different title patterns. But that is not always possible.

Comment: Or you could get all tabs and then use matched_tabs to refine the selection. This way there will be only one single call to ``browser.tabs.query()``

Comment: It's half-possible: the `url` parameter accepts an array of strings, then you'll match the titles on the result e.g. by using `titles.includes(tab.title)`

Comment: @SchokokuchenBäcker both good ideas, thank you! Do you know if there is somewhere that describes the type of pattern matching that is valid here? It doesn't seem to be traditional regex.

Comment: @wOxxOm that's useful information, thank you.

Comment: @pattymills https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Match_patterns This is the documentation of the pattern matching for firefox.